# Django postgres HStoreField order by

Tags: django, postgresql

Can I order the results of QuerySet by values inside of HStoreField, for example I've got model:

```
class Product(model.Models):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    properties = HStoreField()
```

And I want to store some properties of my product in HStoreField like:

```
{ 'discount': '10', 'color': 'white'}
```

In view I want to order the resulting QuerySet by discount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answer does not work. Order transforms were never implemented for `HStoreField`, see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24747.

But the suggestion in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24592 works. Here is some more detail.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import TextField, HStoreField, Model
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

class MyThing(Model):
    name: TextField()
    keys: HStoreField()

things = [MyThing(name='foo'),
          MyThing(name='bar'),
          MyThing(name='baz')]
things[0].keys['movie'] = 'Jaws'
things[1].keys['movie'] = 'Psycho'
things[2].keys['movie'] = 'The Birds'
things[0].keys['rating'] = 5
things[1].keys['rating'] = 4
things[2].keys['year'] = '1963'

# Informal search
MyThing.objects\
    .filter(keys__has_key='rating')\
    .order_by(Func(F('keys'), Value('movie'),
                   function='',
                   arg_joiner=' -> ',
                   output_field=TextField()))
```

The formal search is exactly as described in the second link above. Use the imports in the above snippet with that code.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (I cannot test right now):

```
.order_by("properties -> 'discount'")
```

But be aware that HSTORE values are strings, so you do not get numeric order but instead items are ordered as strings.

Do get proper numeric order, you should extract the `properties->discount` key as separate column and cast it to integer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.